# How to send MIDI messages in Perl?

Tags: perl, hex, messaging, midi, unpack

I am trying to send MIDI messages using Perl. Basically I want to change the patch instrument. Since I am not generating a file, but playing only, I am using [`Win32::MIDI`](https://metacpan.org/release/CHURCH/Win32-MIDI-0_2/view/MIDI.pm) as it is the only module that works for what I require, but there is no module patch instrument method, therefore I am left with `writeMIDI` which requires sending it a MIDI message.

eg.

```
...
# note_on event, channel 1 (0x90), velocity (127), note (127), null (0x00);
my $data_on = "\x00\127\127\x90";     
# note_off event, channel 1 (0x80), velocity (127), note (127), null (0x00);
my $data_off  = "\x00\127\127\x80";

$midi_obj->writeMIDI(unpack("N",$data_on));
sleep(2);
$midi_obj->writeMIDI(unpack("N",$data_off));

$midi_obj->writeMIDI(unpack("N","\x00\C18")); <-- NOT WORKING change instrument on channel # 1 to patch # 8
```

I am trying to do a 'Program Change' on Channel 1, patch no# (eg. 8) as this changes the patch instrument.

as it says in my reference:

A.1. Channel voice messages:

Instruct the receiving instrument to assign particular sounds to its voice
Turn notes on and off
Alter the sound of the currently active note or notes

```
Voice Message         Status Byte     Data Byte1         Data Byte2
Note off                      8x      Key number          Note Off velocity
Note on                       9x      Key number          Note on velocity
Polyphonic Key Pressure       Ax      Key number          Amount of pressure
Control Change                Bx      Controller number   Controller value

Program Change                Cx      Program number      None     

Channel Pressure              Dx      Pressure value      None            
Pitch Bend                    Ex      MSB                 LSB
Notes: `x' in status byte hex value stands for a channel number.
```

Reference I am using
https://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave.Marshall/Multimedia/node158.html

Comment: This does not look right: `unpack("N","\x00\C18\7F")` : There is no escape `\C`. Also  `\7F` is interpreted as `\7` and then an "F". You can write octal escapes using `\xyz` where "x", "y", and "z" are octal numbers (but "C" is not an octal number). What are you trying to write in hex?

Comment: *"I am trying to do a 'Program Change' ..."* : Which channel do you want to change and to which program number?

Comment: the current channel ( channel 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> unpack("N","\x00\C18\7F")

This does not look correct, there is no string escape `\C`. Also if you were trying to write an octal escape, still `C18` and `7F` would  not be octal numbers. Please clarify what you are trying to write in hex.

Some more information on octal escapes can be found in [perlop](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop):

> \033
>
> The result is the character specified by the three-digit octal number
> in the range 000 to 777 (but best to not use above 077, see next
> paragraph)
>
> Some contexts allow 2 or even 1 digit, but any usage without exactly three  digits, the first being a zero, may give unintended results. (For example, in a regular expression it may be confused with a backreference; see "Octal escapes" in `perlrebackslash`.) Starting in Perl 5.14, you may use `\o{}` instead, which avoids all these problems. Otherwise, it is best to use this construct only for ordinals `\077` and below, remembering to pad to the left with zeros to make three digits. For larger ordinals, either use `\o{}`, or convert to something else, such as to hex and use `\N{U+}` (which is portable between platforms with different character sets) or `\x{}` instead.

**Update**:

> I am trying to do a 'Program Change', as this changes the patch instrument.

According to [this](https://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave.Marshall/Multimedia/node158.html) and [this](https://metacpan.org/release/CHURCH/Win32-MIDI-0_2/view/MIDI.pm) you could try something like this:

```
my $channel_number = 1;
my $program_number = 15;
my $unused = 0;
my $str = pack("CCCC", $unused, $unused, $program_number, $channel_number+0xC0);
$midi_obj->writeMIDI(unpack("N",$str));
```

Comment: I get error: Usage: Win32::MIDI::writeMIDI(self, message) at ...

Comment: @JeremyGwa Sorry, I forgot to add a 4th byte (which is unused in this case)